# Memory Management of Interop objects

Tags: c#, memory-management

In an effort to fix possible memory leaks, here is the history behind it: There has been a VB 6.0 or VC 6.0 text editor control that we had to use it in .NET too. So in the assembloy for this control I see some Interop reference to this text editor and then we have created a .NET custom control, dropped that text editor into it and been usig that in projects that need it.

So in Designer.cs file I still see variables like this:

```
private AxTextEditorLib.AxTextEditor ctlTEEditor;
```

and then public properties like this:

```
[Obsolete("This accessor method was added as a convenience for migrating to this component. Remove at earliest convenience.")]
[Browsable(false)]
public AxTextEditor TextEditor
{
    get
    {
        return ctlTEEditor;
    }
}
```

.NET designer itself has generated that standard dispose method for this as follows:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

But is that enough? Do I need more memory handling to do? Do I need to use Marshal.ReleaseObjects or something like that? Do I need to release the event handlers manually?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The effectiveness of calling `Dispose()` is alway dependent on what happens in the chain of `Dispose` calls. So in this instance, the Designer code is calling the `Dispose` method of each component that has been added to the `components` collection.

To work out whether that is useful, you need to look at what components are in the `components` collection, and what the `Dispose` methods of those components do.

Certainly if you have attached event handlers in other parts of the code, then you should ensure that they are unhooked as part of the `Dispose`.

For your wrapped component, it's worth setting it to `null` as part of disposal, but also have a look to see whether it has a Dispose method of its own, or any other methods that may be freeing up resources.

Answer (score 1):

set ctlTEEditor to null if it not already null. Also check the public properties / methods of this control to see if there are any methods exposed to release the memory.